# getting an error when i try to request the bot

Tags: python, discord

Ok so i was building a discord bot using python on repl.it
the thing is that my bot even shows that it's online but whenever i type $hello it just throws the big fat error on my face
[This is the photo of my code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwN3Z.png)

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.send.channel('Hello there young shona follower!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

And this is the error

> Ignoring exception in on_message Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "main.py", line 21, in on_message
> await message.send.channel('Hello there young shona follower!') AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `message.channel.send`, not `message.send.channel`:

```py
await message.channel.send('Hello there young shona follower!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. You cannot call `send` method on `message` object in `on_message` function.